# Hyperledger Fabric minimize transaction size

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

By default, Hyperledger Fabric stored many certificates in transaction before they save to blockchain. Is there anyway or any ideas/techniques to minimize transaction size in blockchain?

Any ideas really appriciated!

Comment: I can't understand what is the relation between the certificates and block size?

Comment: =) I just only explain why I want to minimize the transaction size. Storing many certificates in transaction also is a reason increase transaction size.

Comment: Usually, the certificate\public keys that are stored in the transaction have only the endorser identities, not all identities in the network, which is fine since the endorsement policy will contain the limited endorser peers

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are integral & provide identity to every transaction. Hence, you cannot do away with certificates. You can try minimizing the size of your payload or store something like a hash of the payload & related attributes in the blockchain. In this case, you will have always have a fixed block size.

Comment: Thanks @arnabkaycee

Comment: Maybe you can use the upvote and/or the tick button. ;)